# Configure zookeeper for kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to install kafka in my centos 6.5 machine. In kafka installation tutorial, I came to know that it needs zookeeper to run. I have already install hbase which also uses zookeeper service internally and zookeeper service only starts when I start hbase service.

So in order to install kafka, do I need install zookeeper separately? Please suggest.

Comment: Run a zookeeper instance or cluster and use it for kafka and hbase. We can use the same zookeeper for multiple services. There is a built in zookeeper with the hbase which is not recommended for dev or prod usage. Use a dedicated zookeeper and mention those details in the hbase-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is designed to use zookeeper by default. If you have already installed zookeeper in your system, you can create a bash script to start the zookeeper whenever you start the kafka. On your zookeeper installation directory there should be `zkServer.sh start` (to start zookeeper) and in kafka installation directory `kafka-server-start.sh` (to start the kafka).

Kafka architecture works best with distributed platform, if you are experimenting with sudo cluster, you can look for alternative message brokers like HiveMQ or RabbitMQ.

You can look further discussions at: [Kafka: Is Zookeeper a must?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751708/kafka-is-zookeeper-a-must)

Comment: Thanks ruben for your reply. Anyway I got my answer. I am using kafka inbuilt zookeeper server by following command:

bin/zookeeper-server-started.sh config/zookeeper.properties

Answer (score 0):

Installing the zookeeper cluster is the best practice. You can use it for hbase and kafka.(just define the different root dir in zk)