# Zookeeper failures in Kafka 0.9 and above

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Based of the answer given in [Is Zookeeper a must for Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751708/is-zookeeper-a-must-for-kafka). 
It is clear that what is the responsibility of Zookeeper in Kafka 0.9 and above

I just wanted to understand what will be the impact if zookeeper cluster goes down completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kafka uses ZK for membership (figure out what brokers exist and which of them are alive) and leader election (elect the one broker that is controller for the cluster at any moment).

simply put - if ZK fails kafka dies.

if ZK sneezes (say a particularly long GC pause or a short network connectivity issue) a kafka cluster may temporarily "lose" any number of members and/or the controller. by the time this settles you may have a new controller and new leader brokers for all partitions (which may or may not cause loss of acknowledged data, see "unclean leader election"). I'm not sure if all ongoing transactions would be rolled back - never tried.