# I need to create a kafka image with topics already created

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a requirement that i need to setup kafka locally with topics already there in the container.I am using `ladoop/fast-data-dev` for doing that

How manually i am doing it-

```
docker run -d --name landoopkafka -p 2181:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=localhost landoop/fast-data-dev
```

After running this command my container is up and running.

now i go to bash inside this container like docker -exec -it landopkafka bash

and create topic using this command

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic hello_topic --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

My topic is created.

But my requirement is i need to have a docker file which will have topic created and i just need to run it.

OR

A docker compose file which i need to run

Guys i need help on this ,as i am absolutely new to docker and kafka

Comment: add th command to the end of your `docker run`

Comment: can u help me with the docker file

Comment: @Lin that overrides the CMD, so won't work to keep kafka running

Answer (score 5):

I had to do it too! What if I did not want to use **wurstmeister** images? I decided to make a custom script which will do the job, and run this script in a separate container.

### Repository

https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/kafka-compose

Note, it will work with kafka versions that use **zookeeper**.
[Is Zookeeper a must for Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751708/is-zookeeper-a-must-for-kafka)

***To start kafka with all your topics and zookeeper*** - `docker-compose up -d`.

---

### Implementation details.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# These services are kafka related. This docker-compose allows to start kafka locally quickly.

version: '2.1'

networks:
  demo-network:
    name: demo-network
    driver: bridge

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:${CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION}"
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 32181:32181
    hostname: zookeeper
    networks:
      - demo-network

  kafka:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-kafka:${CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION}"
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 29092:29092

    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka:29092
      LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - "zookeeper"
    networks:
      - demo-network

  # Automatically creates required kafka topics if they were not created.
  kafka-topics-creator:
    build:
      context: kafka-topic-creator
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: kafka-topics-creator
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_HOSTS: "zookeeper:32181"
      KAFKA_TOPICS: "topic_v1 topic_v2"
    networks:
      - demo-network
```

Then I have a directory **kafka-topics-creator**.
Here, I have three files
`create-kafka-topics.sh`, `Dockerfile`, `README.md`.

**Dockerfile**

```
# It is recommened to use same version as kafka broker is used.
# So no additional images are pulled.
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.2

WORKDIR usr/bin

# Once it is executed, this container is not needed.
COPY create-kafka-topics.sh create-kafka-topics.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./create-kafka-topics.sh"]
```

**create-kafka-topics.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Simply wait until original kafka container and zookeeper are started.
sleep 15.0s

# Parse string of kafka topics into an array
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586169/4587961
kafkatopicsArrayString="$KAFKA_TOPICS"
IFS=' ' read -r -a kafkaTopicsArray <<< "$kafkatopicsArrayString"

# A separate variable for zookeeper hosts.
zookeeperHostsValue=$ZOOKEEPER_HOSTS

# Create kafka topic for each topic item from split array of topics.
for newTopic in "${kafkaTopicsArray[@]}"; do
  # https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
  kafka-topics --create --topic "$newTopic" --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --if-not-exists --zookeeper "$zookeeperHostsValue"
done
```

**README.md** - so other people know how to use it.Always document your stuff - good advise.

```
# Creates kafka topics automatically.

## Parameters
`ZOOKEEPER_HOSTS` - zookeeper hosts,  I used value `"zookeeper:32181"` to run it locally.

`KAFKA_TOPICS` - space separated list of kafka topics. Example, `topic_1, topic_2, topic_3`.

Note, this container should run only **after** your original kafka broker and zookeeper are running.
After this container creates topics, it is not needed anymore.
```

### How to check that the topics were created.

One solution is to check logs of `kafka-topics-creator` container.

`docker logs kafka-topics-creator` should print

```
$ docker logs kafka-topics-creator
WARNING: Due to limitations in metric names, topics with a period ('.') or underscore ('_') could collide. To avoid issues it is best to use either, but not both.
Created topic "topic_v1".
WARNING: Due to limitations in metric names, topics with a period ('.') or underscore ('_') could collide. To avoid issues it is best to use either, but not both.
Created topic "topic_v2".
```

Comment: Good, thanks. It is useful, and explains how to provide partitions

Answer (score 2):

You can create a docker-compose file like this...

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
      image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
      image: wurstmeister/kafka:0.10.2.1
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
        KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "MY_TOPIC_ONE:1:1,/
                              MY_TOPIC_TWO:1:1"
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Put your topics there and run `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

You should instead try to use the wurstmeister/kafka image which supports an environment variable to create topics during container startup.

Sure, the Landoop container has a bunch of other useful things, but sounds like you only want Kafka and don't want to mess with editing any Dockerfiles

The other solution is to startup a second container *after Kafka* which runs the create scripts, then stops itself

Comment: is there any way we can do it with using confluentinc kafka image?

Comment: The variable doesn't exist in that image, so you cannot

Comment: @abhisheksingh, yes, please, check y answer bellow.